# Pascals and vacuum pump power

Tags: vacuum

I don't know much about the unit of measure **pascal** to estimate the performance of a vacuum pump.

On a vacuum pump, it says that it can reach the pressure of $3\times10^{-1}\,\mbox{Pa}$. I've been trying to find out if it has a strong vacuum.

The pump I have currently have at the moment is rated at $5\,\mbox{Pa}$ and I need a new pump with a stronger vacuum. Is $3\times10^{-1}\,\mbox{Pa}$ stronger than $5\,\mbox{Pa}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure is defined as the force applied perpendicular to the surface of an object per unit area over which that force is distributed
\begin{equation}
P = \frac{dF}{dA}
\end{equation}

In SI units, the force is measured in newton $\mbox{N}$ and the surface in square meters $\mbox{m}^2$.
The unit of measure for pressure in the SI is the *pascal* ($\mbox{Pa}$), which is defined newton per square meter
\begin{equation}
[\mbox{Pa}] = \frac{[\mbox{N}]}{[\mbox{m}]^2}
\end{equation}

A lower value of pascal means lower pressure in your system and hence a higher grade of vacuum.

Other specifications of the pump are important as well when setting up a vacuum system. For example, you want to check also the pumping speed is high enough for your requirements.

The pumping speed is defined as the volume flow through the pump. The pumping speed tells you how fast you will approach the pressure that your pump is rated for. If the pumping speed is too little compared to the volume you want to evacuate, you will take a very long time to reach your goal pressure. This is further worsened by the presence of leaks (every system has them to some degree).

PS. the rating of a vacuum pump is often expressed as the *ultimate vacuum* it can reach in ideal conditions. Expect your system to have (hopefully slightly) worse performance.

**TLDR:** yes generally a pump rated to reach $3\times 10^{-1}\,\mbox{Pa}$ can obtain a lower pressure (=stronger vacuum) than a pump rated for $5\,\mbox{Pa}$.

Comment: Great answer thank you! that helps a lot.